# Kable output in RStudio contains raw unformatted html

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I'm experimenting with kable in RStudio. My color formatting instructions are being output as raw html rather than formatted:

[image]

Example:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

install.packages("kableExtra")

library("tidyverse")
library("kableExtra")
```
 

```{r }
dt = tribble(
  ~Type, ~Image,              ~Days, ~Case1_f, ~Case1_p, ~Case1_m, ~Case1_sd,
  "1-1",  "kableExtra_sm.png", 1,    0.01,     0.14,    0.54,     1.06,
  "1-1",  "kableExtra_sm.png", 2,    0.01,     0.74,    0.54,     1.06,
  "1-2",  "kableExtra_sm.png", 1,    0.01,     0.74,    0.54,     1.06,
  "1-2",  "kableExtra_sm.png", 2,    0.01,     0.14,    0.54,     1.06,
)

dt$Case1_p = cell_spec(dt$Case1_p, color = ifelse(dt$Case1_p > 0.5, "red", "blue"))

dt %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_styling()


```
````

I've tried various {R} and kbl() parameters, including results='asis' and format='html' to no effect.  What am I missing here, please?

Comment: Maybe try `kbl(escape = F)` for your raw html?

Comment: That's the magic phrase.  Thanks Ben!

Answer (score 0):

Comment from @Ben is correct answer:

> Maybe try kbl(escape = F) for your raw html? – Ben